# How to emulate javascript in Mechanize?

Tags: javascript, perl, postback, mechanize

How can I run this `JavaScript` using `perl` `Mechanize`?

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
        var theform;
        if (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") > -1) {
            theform = document.Form1;
        }
        else {
            theform = document.forms["Form1"];
        }
        theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget.split("$").join(":");
        theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theform.submit();
    }
```

Comment: Using the https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox#mech-eval_in_page-str-env-document maybe could help....

Comment: Does that require Firefox to be installed? Because it isn't installed on the server I am working on.

Comment: Yes, it needs the FF... :( and also the Mozrepl plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mech->form_name("Form1");
$mech->field("__EVENTTARGET", $eventTarget);
$mech->field("__EVENTARGUMENT", $eventArgument);
$mech->submit();
```

Comment: Your "solution" is nice - just it isn't "runs" the JS, just emulates what the JS does ;) :)